# What does simplest optically active alkene mean?

Tags: organic-chemistry, stereochemistry

I am confused between whether we will call 2,3-dimethyl-cyclopropene or 3-methylpent-1-ene as simplest optically active alkene. Does “simplest” mean aliphatic, or does it mean having least number of carbon atoms?

Comment: That's kinda opinion based. Somehow, I doubt I've ever seen a definition of simplicity of compound. I could also beat your idea using deuterium and tritium instead of two methyl groups.

Answer (score 2):

In chemistry, *simple* generally refers to compounds of low molecular masses. So simplest
optically alkene would mean the alkene with lowest molecular mass. Hence 2,3,dimethyl-cyclopropene would be your *simplest optically active alkene*.

Comment: Optical activity can also refer to the process. I have seen problems that refer to differing yields in terms of racemate, and from this optical activity was determined.